# Why is puppeteer reporting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!"?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I've got a simple node.js script to capture screenshots of a few web pages. It appears I'm getting tripped up somewhere along the line with my use of async/await, but I can't figure out where. I'm currently using puppeteer v1.11.0.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//a list of sites to screenshot
const papers =
{
     nytimes: "https://www.nytimes.com/",
     wapo: "https://www.washingtonpost.com/"
};

//launch puppeteer, do everything in .then() handler
puppeteer.launch({devtools:false}).then(function(browser){

//create a load_page function that returns a promise which resolves when screenshot is taken
async function load_page(paper){

    const url = papers[paper];

    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width:1024, height: 768});

        //screenshot on first console message
        page.once("console", async console_msg => {        
            await page.pdf({path: paper + '.pdf',
                            printBackground:true,
                            width:'1024px',
                            height:'768px',
                            margin: {top:"0px", right:"0px", bottom:"0px", left:"0px"}
                        });

            //close page
            await page.close();

            //resolve promise
            resolve();
        });

        //go to page
        await page.goto(url, {"waitUntil":["load", "networkidle0"]});

    })     
}

//step through the list of papers, calling the above load_page()
async function stepThru(){
    for(var p in papers){
        if(papers.hasOwnProperty(p)){
            //wait to load page and screenshot before loading next page
            await load_page(p);
        }
    }

    //close browser after loop has finished (and all promises resolved)
    await browser.close();  
}

//kick it off
stepThru();

//getting this error message:
//UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!

});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `Navigation failed because browser has disconnected` error usually means that the node scripts that launched Puppeteer ends without waiting for the Puppeteer actions to be completed. Hence it's a problem with some waitings as you told.

About your script, I made some changes to make it work:

1. First of all you're not awaiting the (async) end of the `stepThru` function so change

```js
stepThru();
```

to

```js
await stepThru();
```

and

```js
puppeteer.launch({devtools:false}).then(function(browser){
```

to

```js
puppeteer.launch({devtools:false}).then(async function(browser){
```

(I added `async`)

2. I changed the way you manage the `goto` and `page.once` promises

The PDF promise is now:

```js
new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
    //screenshot on first console message
    page.once("console", async () => {
      await page.pdf({
        path: paper + '.pdf', 
        printBackground:true, 
        width:'1024px', 
        height:'768px', 
        margin: {
          top:"0px", 
          right:"0px", 
          bottom:"0px", 
          left:"0px"
        } 
      });
      resolve();
    });
})
```

and it has a single responsibility, just the PDF creation.

3. Then I managed both the `page.goto` and PDF promises with a `Promise.all`

```js
await Promise.all([
    page.goto(url, {"waitUntil":["load", "networkidle2"]}),
    new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
        // ... pdf creation as above        
    })
]);
```

4. I moved the `page.close` after the `Promise.all`

```js
await Promise.all([
    // page.goto
    // PDF creation
]);

await page.close();
resolve();
```

And now it works, here the full working script:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//a list of sites to screenshot
const papers =
{
  nytimes: "https://www.nytimes.com/",
  wapo: "https://www.washingtonpost.com/"
};

//launch puppeteer, do everything in .then() handler
puppeteer.launch({devtools:false}).then(async function(browser){

  //create a load_page function that returns a promise which resolves when screenshot is taken
  async function load_page(paper){
    const url = papers[paper];
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({width:1024, height: 768});

      await Promise.all([
        page.goto(url, {"waitUntil":["load", "networkidle2"]}),
        new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){

          //screenshot on first console message
          page.once("console", async () => {
            await page.pdf({path: paper + '.pdf', printBackground:true, width:'1024px', height:'768px', margin: {top:"0px", right:"0px", bottom:"0px", left:"0px"} });
            resolve();
          });
        })
      ]);

      await page.close();
      resolve();
    })
  }

  //step through the list of papers, calling the above load_page()
  async function stepThru(){
    for(var p in papers){
      if(papers.hasOwnProperty(p)){
        //wait to load page and screenshot before loading next page
        await load_page(p);
      }
    }

    await browser.close();
  }

  await stepThru();
});
```

Please note that:

- I changed `networkidle0` to `networkidle2` because the nytimes.com website takes a very long time to land a 0 network requests state (because of the AD etc.). You can wait for `networkidle0` obviously but it's up to you, it's out of the scope of your question (increase the `page.goto` timeout in that case).
- The `www.washingtonpost.com` site goes to `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error so I changed to `washingtonpost.com` but I think that you should investigate more about it. To test the script I used more times the `nytimes` site and other websites. Again: it's out of the scope of your question.

Let me know if you need some more help

Comment: This was a really nice, detailed answer, thanks!  One question, is there a reason you chose to resolve() the PDF promise immediately, rather than placing resolve inside of page.once() callback?

Comment: It was a mistake, I fixed it. Both work but I think that the first one was just a lucky case 

Comment: you don't need to use `async` if you are not awaiting in the function, e.g. `async function load_page(paper)` become `function load_page(paper)`

Answer (score 8):

I Had the same error when system disk was full.

Comment: How do U check if this?